# Is time.sleep() impacting the ZeroMQ poller.poll() response?

Tags: python, zeromq, distributed-computing, pyzmq, low-latency

I'm getting results I can't explain when making a ZeroMQ **`REQ/REP`** request with polling.

The elapsed time, taken by the `poll()`-method, is influenced by a `time.sleep()` elsewhere in the code.

I have a server process which runs a command, and returns the `pid` of the process. This is the request side code which has the issue:

```
import datetime, sys, time, zmq

sleeptime = float(sys.argv[1])

def log_msg(msg):
    print "{0}, {1}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S.%f'), msg)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://{0}:{1}".format('myserver', 9980))
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
req = { 'req_type':'raw_cmd', 'cmd':'echo hello', 'block':0, 'timeout':300, 'return_output': 0}

for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    socket.send_json(req)
    start = time.time()
    socks = dict((poller.poll(30000)))
    elapsed = (time.time()-start)*1000
    rep = socket.recv_json()
    log_msg('pid={0}, sleep={1}, time taken={2}'.format(rep['pid'], sleeptime, int(elapsed)))
```

The first poll elapsed time is quite variable, but all the subsequent ones take about 2 seconds less the sleep time, unless sleep time is 0, in which case it's fast, so:

`sleep = 0.5` :

```
20201008_08:27:24.168800, pid=52528, sleep=0.5, time taken=505
20201008_08:27:26.210196, pid=52529, sleep=0.5, time taken=1540
20201008_08:27:28.250891, pid=52530, sleep=0.5, time taken=1539
20201008_08:27:30.295036, pid=52531, sleep=0.5, time taken=1543
```

`sleep = 1.5` :

```
20201008_08:44:02.474492, pid=54730, sleep=1.5, time taken=295
20201008_08:44:04.516844, pid=54731, sleep=1.5, time taken=540
20201008_08:44:06.557980, pid=54732, sleep=1.5, time taken=539
20201008_08:44:08.599717, pid=54733, sleep=1.5, time taken=539
```

`sleep = 0` :

```
20201008_08:27:13.999147, pid=52513, sleep=0.0, time taken=690
20201008_08:27:14.033915, pid=52514, sleep=0.0, time taken=34
20201008_08:27:14.068803, pid=52515, sleep=0.0, time taken=34
20201008_08:27:14.103947, pid=52516, sleep=0.0, time taken=34
```

So question is, why does the `time.sleep()` affect the time taken by the ZeroMQ `poller.poll()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as-is mixes apples with oranges:

**`time.time()`** returns seconds since epoch as **`float`**, i.e. **`( time.time() - start )*1000`** yields how many `[ms]` milliseconds the code-section under test actually took.

Whereas the **`poller.poll()`**-method expects milliseconds for it's *`timeout`*, so the requested `30000 [ms]`  makes the `poller`-instance wait and hold until `30 [s]` elapse or a message-arrival related `zmq.POLLIN`-event permits to step forwards anywhere earlier.

This said, your measurement explores not the `.sleep()`-method, but intervals taken at random by an external process, that sends **`REP`**-side answers to **`REQ`**-side `.send()`-s.

Still in doubts? Set sleeptime to **`31 [s]`** and you ought receive almost zero durations reported from an ill-formulated local time-bracket (sure, if and only if the remote `REP`-lying entity did not crash of suffocate during such ops).

You might also like `zmq.Stopwatch` class, having `{ .start(), .stop() }`-methods, that provide a smart tool for using a ZeroMQ native `[us]`-resolution-clock. Most of my [posts on ZeroMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20Stopwatch) performance use this for microbenchmarking.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the issue. The external process is fairly constant in its response, taking 30-40 ms, as can be seen in the 0 sleep case. When the sleep is increased however, up to 2 seconds, the poller takes 2+response_time-sleep_time (for each call after the first). i.e. the sleep time is impacting the time the poller takes. I don't understand why this would be.

Comment: @JoeWatkins I can make you sure I do my best to understand your issue. The best next step is to make the claimed problem reproducible - would you mind to post the complete, end-to-end working code, that represents the whole ecosystem under review? I look forward for the still missing details about the REP-side code and the about the topology and capacities of the [tag:distributed-computing] system.

Comment: Oh dear.. so the REP code is too large to put here, so I did a cut-down version, and no problem seen.
I've now noticed a sleep(2) that shouldn't be there in the server code, and this is the issue.
I think I need to delete this question, as it's entirely my fault
Thanks for your time @user3666197